# VueJS + Quasar Framework + Google Maps JS API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps-api-3, quasar

could you please help me to import Google Maps API to my VUE app created with Quasar Framework?

I have installed [google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps)

I have followed the instructions [here](https://quasar-framework.org/guide/app-plugins.html#Usage-of-app-plugins) and I create a gmapApi.js file

```
import GoogleMapsLoader from 'google-maps'
// leave the export, even if you don't use it
export default ({ app, router, Vue }) => {
   Vue.prototype.$gmaps = GoogleMapsLoader
   Vue.prototype.$gmaps.KEY = 'MY-KEY'
   Vue.prototype.$gmaps.LIBRARIES = ['places']
}
```

Then I added gmapApi on my quasar.conf.js under plugins

```
// app plugins (/src/plugins)
plugins: [
  'gmapApi'
]
```

Then, how do I reference the gmap in a Vue component? lets say I want to [reverse geolocate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) a position

I tried

```
var geocoder = new this.$gmaps.maps.Geocoder()
```

But I get an error that maps is undefined.

What am I missing here? Am I even on the right track?

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, found it

```
   this.$gmaps.load(function (google) {
      let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
      let point = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
      console.log(point)
      geocoder.geocode({'latLng': point}, function (locations, status) {
        console.log(status + ' ' + locations)
      })
    })
```